# How to remove content from url after question mark. preg_match or preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Im working on some function to grab few data from url with simple html dom.

But one of the data is an image and image have question mark and some more info behind it.

So example of url would be something like this.

```
http://somesite.com/uploaded/images/8.jpg?m=eSuQKgaaaa&mh=t0i7nVhjZleTJ5Ih
```

So this content behind question mark is some sort of the code that makes images resized to small size.

If i would just take this

```
http://somesite.com/uploaded/images/8.jpg
```

Images would be in bigger resolution and that's what i need.

I know there is a function like preg_match but i never understood expressions in it.

Is it possible that i somehow remove questionmark and all the content behind it ?

Comment: There's a function for parsing URLs in PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even easier: use `explode()`:

```
list($uri,) = explode('?', 'http://somesite.com/uploaded/images/8.jpg?m=eSuQKgaaaa&mh=t0i7nVhjZleTJ5Ih');
```

**update**

Or simpler yet use [strtok](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) and [trim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
$uri = trim(strtok('http://somesite.com/uploaded/images/8.jpg?m=eSuQKgaaaa&mh=t0i7nVhjZleTJ5Ih', '?'));
```

Normally you would use `parse_url()` for working with URLs but in a case like this, using `explode()` is simpler to use and serve's your purpose.

Comment: Ok that worked, so ended up with $get_thumb = explode('?', $url); $thumb = $get_thumb[0]; and $url is url of image.

Answer (score 1):

In a much easier way it could be:

```
$iWantThisURL = substr($curr_url(), 0, stripos($curr_url, '?'));
```